# static text not updating on MFC dialog box

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to update some static text when I click a button but for some reason the text doesn't update. I have done this before and checked previous code that I have written and I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

```
public:
CString m_console;

CString m_output;
CString text1;
};

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
     CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

     DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_OUTPUT, m_output);

}

CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::CMandelbrotExperimentDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
: CDialogEx(IDD_MANDELBROTEXPERIMENT_DIALOG, pParent)
, m_output(_T(""))
{

    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnBnClickedBtnCompile()
{

     CWnd* okbtn = GetDlgItem(IDC_BTNCOMPILE);
     if (okbtn) {
        okbtn->EnableWindow(FALSE);
     }

     stopNow = 0;
     SetTimer(1234, 333, 0); // 3 times per second
     m_output = "Bulding Fractal, please wait..";


     AfxBeginThread(compileMandelbrot, this);

     UpdateData(false);

  }
```

Comment: What is the relationship, if any, between `CAboutDlg` and `CMandelbrotExperimentDlg`?

Comment: That's it! I need to go to specsavers!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change:

```
void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
      CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
      DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_OUTPUT, m_output);

 }
```

to

```
void CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
     CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
     DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_OUTPUT, m_output);
}
```